# RAILS TUTORIAL & HEROKU DEPLOYMENT :rake aborted! Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

Hi I've been following www.railstutorial.org's tutorial, when I need to deploy my code to heroku and do 'heroku run rake db:migrate' it keep throw me the same error

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the  minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

this is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.36.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.1'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'puma',           '3.1.0'
end
```

I've done bundle install and it all works fine on my local machine, just can't update my heroku db, and my heroku app always give me 'Application Error'.

all my code is actually in github and you can see it [here](https://github.com/liangsu1210/static_page)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using an old version of the pg gem. Try removing the version and run bundle update pg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the gem pg is only loaded in your local environment. Delete your Gemfile.lock file and run `bundle install` then commit to your github -> `git add -A`, `git commit -m "some message"`, `git push`, then do `git push heroku master`
heroku run rake db:migrate should work now.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I've tried your solution and still the same error, and then I tried `heroku run rails console`. console still give me the same error, and I honestly don't know what I done wrong

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your `database.yml` file in the config folder.

In this file you are using `sqlite3` as your database. you need to modify this file if you want to use postgresql.

For example you would replace all code in the `database.yml` file with the following if you want to use postgresql for development, test and production:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: NAMEOFDATABASE_development
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: NAMEOFDATABASE_test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: NAMEOFDATABASE_production
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

If you only want to use `postgresql` for production the only modify the production code

Also, you should declare your ruby version at the top of your `gemfile` by placing this: `ruby '2.3.1'` at the top. Obviously change the version if you are using a different version

See [This](https://medium.com/@helenflam/how-to-change-your-rails-app-database-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-before-deploying-to-heroku-ae2acc25c7ac#.fade7tls6) and [This](http://watabelabs.com/blog/view/migrating-rails-application-data-from-sqlite3-to-postgresql) for more details on converting your database from sqlite to postgresql

Comment: thanks, but it still not resolved, same error, I've found author's github and compared the code, on `database.yml` he had left it [default](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_3rd_edition/blob/32c92110534f5e4d2bf6056f561023757295e136/config/database.yml) . looks like heroku is looking for pg but it clearly in my `gemfile`